# Why is FastCGI fast?

Tags: perl, fastcgi

> FastCGI provides a way to improve the
>   performance of the thousands of Perl
>   applications that have been written
>   for the Web. -[Source](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/)

and how does it do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the "not a real question" votes. Seems reasonable enough to me.

Comment: It appears as though the answer was a mere two clicks away..... http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/16

Comment: @awoodland Agreed. The question could use a quick edit, but it's certainly valid. @Jack Maney Nothing wrong with having the answer here, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mark R. Brown's [whitepaper on the subject](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/16#S3) claims that one of the primary benefits of FastCGI is that different requests can share a single cache, making caching practical:

> Today's most widely deployed Web server APIs are based on a pool-of-processes server model. The Web server consists of a parent process and a pool of child processes. Processes do not share memory. An incoming request is assigned to an idle child at random. The child runs the request to completion before accepting a new request. A typical server has 32 child processes, a large server has 100 or 200.
>
> In-memory caching works very poorly in this server model because processes do not share memory and incoming requests are assigned to processes at random. For instance, to keep a frequently-used file available in memory the server must keep a file copy per child, which wastes memory. When the file is modified all the children need to be notified, which is complex (the APIs don't provide a way to do it).
>
> FastCGI is designed to allow effective in-memory caching. Requests are routed from any child process to a FastCGI application server. The FastCGI application process maintains an in-memory cache.

Answer (score 8):

> "Instead of creating a new process for
>   each request, FastCGI uses persistent
>   processes to handle a series of
>   requests. These processes are owned by
>   the FastCGI server, not the web
>   server."

-- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI#Implementation_details)

Answer (score 4):

It reuses processes from a pool instead of spawning a new one for every request.

Comment: There are lots of (positive) side-effects of re-using processes: maybe you could elaborate?